# Check if user has a role in the new discord.js version

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hey I wanted to check if a user had a role, although all other methods are quite outdated and I've tried a couple of things, none of them work.

My attempt:

```
var guild = client.guilds.cache.get("Guild ID")
var buyerRole = guild.roles.cache.get("Role ID")
await guild.members.fetch()
const guildMember =  guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
if(guildMember.roles.find(buyerRole.id)){...
```

Comment: It's roles.cache.find, and you are only using ID so use roles.cache.has

Comment: But `find()` accepts a function, not an ID, so probably `roles.cache.has(buyerRole.id)`

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros `TypeError: authorMember.roles.find is not a function` :(

Comment: Check the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70369808/check-if-user-has-a-role-in-the-new-discord-js-version?noredirect=1#comment124392946_70369808) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70369808/check-if-user-has-a-role-in-the-new-discord-js-version?noredirect=1#comment124392966_70369808) answers

Comment: @MrMythical `TypeError: authorMember.roles.has is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of debugging, it turns out that you can use
`message.author._roles` instead of `message.author.roles` in order to get the complete list array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're going to want to use member.roles.cache.some() to achieve this.

```
var guild = client.guilds.cache.get("Guild ID")
var buyerRole = guild.roles.cache.get("Role ID")
const guildMember = await guild.members.fetch('User ID');
if(guildMember.roles.cache.some(x => x.id == buyerRole.id)){...
```

.some will always return a boolean, so it's better for you to use it like that.

Comment: `guildMember.roles.cache.has(buyerRole.id)` does the same and shorter.